# How to directly access kernel data for processes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, proc

In windows there is an api like GetProcessMemoryInfo for example. It queries kernel syscall and returns to caller a binary structure for further processing. In Linux I can only see that everyone is reading /proc pid contents. On a large scales when I need to collect a lot of info and very often this becomes a problem. The problem is in many levels

- why should I access filesystem and do a search for a syscall by a string key, if I can know call name directly prior call in a binary program?
- data, originally comes as binary structs then was converted to text, marshalled, it was a CPU waste in my case.
- I have to waste CPU again to unmarshal data back to binary form

Can I get that data directly by invoking some function of kernel directly, eg I want to get same data as obtained by parsing proc pid stat file, but without accessing that file, in optimized path?

Comment: AFAIK, Linux has deliberately chosen not to provide an API to get the data in binary, most likely because of the portability and forward compatibility problems it causes.  Yes, there is a tradeoff in CPU usage; can you really prove that it is so large that it significantly impacts your program?

Comment: @NateEldredge This approach can be good for small bash script, but not suitable for a large cluster node binary collector which wants to sample metrics for tons of things often enough. What is the problem adding new fields at the end of binary structure? Also if you will add text to the end some text parsers may break as well. I don't understand benefit of text api, one can make change to make it not compatible because it's not even json which can offer compatibility, but its a raw values space/newline separated. I can reorder couple or insert in the middle as with binary and it will break

Comment: Well, I'm not the one to be debating you over it.  But you might research the compatibility difficulties that the Linux kernel had with `stat`.  Remember the kernel has to provide *binary* compatibility: they can't make the struct larger or change its layout in any way, because the user's program was built expecting a particular layout and won't be recompiled.  (And remember the Unix API returns structs by copying them into a user-supplied buffer of predefined size; if you enlarge the struct you overrun the buffer).

Comment: So the only way to add more fields is to create a new version of the system call that returns a different struct, and then only newly compiled programs can use it.  And that would force them to support all these different syscall versions for all eternity, as the ABI is promised to be backward compatible essentially forever.

Comment: Found this. But is seems not to be everywhere.. https://lwn.net/Articles/685791/

Comment: I don't think that `task_diag` was ever accepted into the mainline kernel.